# Using remove_reference in function header

Tags: c++, c++11

Say I have the following:

```
template <typename... A>
class MyClass
{
public:

    void func(A... args)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
};
```

What I really want is for func() to take l-value references, so something like this:

```
template <typename... A>
class MyClass
{
public:

    void func(std::remove_reference<A>::type&... args)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
};
```

This doesn't compile; is this sort of thing possible? Thanks.

Comment: clang error:  "error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'std::remove_reference<A>::type'"

Answer (score 1):

The code should read

```
template <typename... A>
class MyClass
{
public:

    void func(typename std::remove_reference<A>::type&... args)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
};
```

Comment: Note that with C++14 you can simply use: `void func(std::remove_reference_t<A>&... args) { ... }`